# Bootstrap display property gap fix

Tags: html, twitter, display

I have this div row that I would like to have adjusted when the window size changes.

```
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 d-block d-sm-none d-xs-none text-center">
     <a href="" class="btn my-4" role="button"> Login </a>
     <span class="or-spacer my-auto">or</span>
     <a href="" class="btn my-4" role="button"> Register </a>
     <br>
     <p>to claim this coupon</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 text-left d-none d-md-block d-lg-block d-xl-block">
     <a href="" class="btn my-4" role="button"> Login </a>
     <span class="or-spacer my-auto">or</span>
     <a href="" class="btn my-4" role="button"> Register </a>
     <span class="or-spacer my-auto">to claim this coupon</span>
   </div>
  </div>
```

I followed the classes in this bootstrap page: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

the top div displays on size sm and below and the bottom one shows on size md and above.

The problem is there is a small gap in between md and sm that displays neither of the two. The Login and Register buttons disappear.

**md+**

[image: md]

**between md and sm (no display)**

[image: btw]

**sm-**

[image: sm]

What can be changed for the no display in between md and sm?

Comment: What gap? The one below **Price to pay** in **no display**? If so, did you check in the dev tools what causes that gap if any?

Comment: The Login and Register Buttons disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no gap between `sm` and `md`

`sm` ranges till `767px` while `md` starts from `768px`

Try this :

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="d-none d-md-block">
     visible for md and above
   </div>

   <div class="d-block d-md-none">
    visible for sm and below
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to change `d-sm-none` to `d-md-none` in your sm block:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 d-block d-md-none d-xs-none text-center">
     <a href="" class="btn my-4" role="button"> Login </a>
     <span class="or-spacer my-auto">or</span>
     <a href="" class="btn my-4" role="button"> Register </a>
     <br>
     <p>to claim this coupon</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 text-left d-none d-md-block d-lg-block d-xl-block">
     <a href="" class="btn my-4" role="button"> Login </a>
     <span class="or-spacer my-auto">or</span>
     <a href="" class="btn my-4" role="button"> Register </a>
     <span class="or-spacer my-auto">to claim this coupon</span>
   </div>
  </div>
```